# UITextField cursor position does not positioned to same location after changing location with magnifying glass

Tags: ios, objective-c

my application textfield width in 60 and it shows clear button while editing,after entering text(more than textfield size means take 15 character) and moving cursor using magnifying glass it does not show the same position where i left with magnifying glass because textfield size is small.
is there any other way to handle that.i cannot increase textfield size.

Thanks

Comment: i created a textField as u mentioned, but i didn't see your problem on my device (iOS 8.0.2)

Comment: after scrolling with magnifying glass when we release it then textfield cursor is not same as when we release on the time of magnifying.

Comment: this problem not occurred for me

Comment: your clear button should be enabled while magnifying and after releasing from magnifying glass.clear button frame comes over the text after magnifying glass.

Answer (score 1):

i pasted some screenshots that got in my ipad mini iOS ver 7.0.3

[image]

After releasing my hand

[image]

Comment: how many text you have entered? enter 10 to 12 character and scroll cursor while magnifying you will not be able to scroll in the middle because scrolling is fast and after releasing if you released at 5 or 6th char then it will show cursor on 3rd char.

Comment: @johnykumar 15 characters (123456789012345)

Comment: @johnykumar what is your textField's superView?

Comment: tableview cell i have added that with xib

Comment: @johnykumar now i tested in table view cell... is that your textField is subclass of UITextField? or its just an object of UITextField?

Comment: its just an textfield which i dragged in xib.

Comment: @johnykumar is textField in any corner of the screen?? does the magnifying glass visible fully??

Comment: yes glass is visible fully it is not in the corner its happening because in magnifying glass its scroll to particular postion but while coming back to textfield because of clear button its position goes changed